# Node.js / Express / Socket.io Not working on Localhost but works by going direct file

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, localhost

I'm developing a multi-player HTML5 game using Node.js for an Express server and Socket.io for websockets. When I try to access the game in my browser going to the port the application is listening to, I get a blank page. However, when I access the index.html file directly (while the server is running), it works perfectly.

Note, when I say "access the file directly" I mean: file:///C:/Program%20Files/nodejs/SupermarketChallenge/public/index.html

This was fine until I wanted to test the game with my housemate who needs to access it through localhost in order to play!

Here's the relevant server code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    //Create an express server
    app = express.createServer(),
    //attach socket.io to the server
    supermarket = require('socket.io').listen(app);

//Configure a static directory for public files
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

//set the port to listen to
app.listen(3000);
```

And the client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because going to `http://localhost:3000/` does not match any valid files from your public folder.  You need a route to match this.  Update your code according:

```
var express = require('express'),
    //Create an express server
    app = express.createServer(),
    //attach socket.io to the server
    supermarket = require('socket.io').listen(app);

//Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/index.html');
});

//Configure a static directory for public files
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

//set the port to listen to
app.listen(3000);
```

Now your route can be altered to actually serve the content of the `index.html`, in which case you would replace the `/` route with the following:

```
//Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This didn't solve it but I think it may be due to my ambiguous wording. If I access the file at localhost:3000/index.html it doesn't work. It's when I access the file through the file system e.g.
    file:///C:/Program%20Files/nodejs/SupermarketChallenge/public/index.html

Then it does work. 

Also, I have a <div> for some debugging output text. This does load using localhost, but the canvas is just completely blank.

Comment: Well this seems like a problem not to do with the server more so as to where your client scripts are pointing to, as far as pathing.  I would suggest doing some debugging in chrome to see if the Websocket is even connecting.  socket.io on the server by default should be outputting debug level messages to the console.  Make sure your seeing activity.  Aside from all of that, maybe posting a bit more of your client scripts could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = { /* ... */ };
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);

io.on("connection", socket => { /* ... */ });

httpServer.listen(3000);
// WARNING !!! app.listen(3000); will not work here, as it creates a new HTTP server
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what the code is doing?

Comment: Actually express is making a server and giving that server to httpServer so we have to use httpServer.listen instead of app.listen